Book - Due to a virus/disease, girl's sister changes into a chrysalis, is hidden in old tower, and then hatches into a flying moth creature
This was a book about sisters (possibly twins?), where one of them starts to change into a chrysalis-type thing, after contracting some sort of virus. Rather than telling the authorities, the sister hides the chrysalis in an old water tower/church tower. After some time the chrysalis hatches into a sort of moth type thing, the sister has to tie a rope to the moth as it keeps trying to fly out of the tower. Eventually she lets it go and it flies out, but the sister finds that she can feel/see what the moth-thing can see, through a telepathic type link. I read this at least 10 years + ago.
